# Specific question about len() of the collatz count

Tags: python, python-3.x, collatz

I have this code where it conducts the  collatz sequence:

```
x0 = int(input('Enter number:'))

while x0 > 1:

    print(x0)
    if (x0 % 2):
        x0 = 3*x0 + 1
    else:
        x0 = x0//2
```

The answer it gives me is 4 and 2 written above one another. Is there any way to put the length of the answer. I tried it with `len()` but it didn't word. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is "the answer" so to speak? Can you give an example of what you're expecting?

Comment: For example: instead of this: Enter number:4 --> 4 2    I want it to give me:2 . So the length of the 'sequence'

Comment: just use a counter variable that keeps track of counts as you go through your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a track of how many iterations you're going through by using a counter variable.

```
count = 0
while x0 > 1:
    count += 1
    #print(x0)
    if (x0 % 2):
        x0 = 3*x0 + 1
    else:
        x0 = x0//2

print(count)
```